# Delete JS cookie after midnight

Tags: javascript, cookies

On my website, I'm displaying an overlay and setting a cookie after it's closed by the user. The cookie expires at midnight and I understand I cannot check with JS whether the cookie is still valid. All I can do is retrieve its value.

Basically, I need to know if the cookie is set (not to show the overlay) AND if the user accesses the website after midnight (to show the overlay again). I was thinking about something like this:

1. Set the cookie with the value of timestamp representing midight.
2. On page load, compare current timestamp with the value of the cookie - and delete the cookie if needed.

Is there a better way to do it? I'm not asking for the code, but for an advice.

Comment: You could do that, but if the cookie has expired then just getting its value (and getting nothing back) will tell you that.

Comment: Is that midnight *your* time or the user's time? By default, JS is going to use the time on the user's computer.

Comment: @vch, The website is dedicated to one country, one specific language, I don't mind timezones at this point.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, If the value of a cookie is set to `TRUE`, isn't it still `TRUE` after the cookie expires?

Comment: I would simply set the expire date for the cookie at midnight. It will automatically get deleted by the browser then

Comment: Well no, because it's expired...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, of course, I knew that all along, but my code said otherwise - as I was checking the cookie always after it was set... I will go and kill myself now, if you guys don't mind. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that, you need two cookies A and B:

A stores the date when setting B.

B stores the status that whether to show the overlay or not.

You need to do the following:

Check A when loading the page, if A is not current date, clean B.

Check B whether to show the overlay.

On user closing the overlay, set B and current date to A.